# Invalid use of template-name 'BigNumber' without an argument list

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi I keep having this error message for the part "BigNumber B1,B2,RES;" where at the button, can any1 help me out please, here is the code. I tried adding to the class, but none of them worked, I know t his might be simple for alot of guys here,but I just starting to do c++, I am still trying to get the hang of it, so please help, many thanks.

```
    template <class T>

    class BigNumber {


    public:
      BigNumber();
      ~BigNumber();
    };

    template <class T>
    BigNumber<T>::BigNumber(){
        front = NULL;
        current = NULL;
    }

    template <class T>
    BigNumber<T>::~BigNumber(){
    }


    BigNumber B1,B2,RES;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigNumber` is template class. So, you have to provide arguments to substitute for template parameters.

```
Bignumber<int> B1;
```

Here `int` is template argument which would replace template parameter `T`.

Comment: I just tried it, BigNumber <int>B1,B2,RES; seems the error has gone away, thx